# I can't solve this Algebra 1 equation: For how long did she run?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Before going to school, Eudora ran from her home to a secret laboratory at an average speed of 12 km/h. Since she was running late, she then took one of her jetpacks and flew to her school at an average speed of 76 km/h. Eudora traveled a total distance of 120 kilometers, and the entire trip took 2 hours.
How long did Eudora spend running, and how long did she spend flying using her jetpack?

I have tried this so far:

$r$ = time spent running;
$f$ = time spent flying.

$r$ + $f$ = 2
$\frac{r}{12}$Km+$\frac{f}{76}$Km = 120km

In order to get rid of the 12, I multiplied:

(-12)($\frac{r}{12}$Km+$\frac{f}{76}$Km) = 120km(-12)

= -$r$ - $\frac{12}{76}f$ = -1440

I added the two equations:

$r$ + $f$ = 2

+

-$r$ - $\frac{12}{76}f$ = -1440

---

$\frac{64}{76}f$=-1440

When I simplify this, I get a huge answer in the thousands.

All of the equations that I have tried are wrong. I don't know what the answer is and I have been stuck on this one for a while now. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: If she spent time $r$ running at $12$ kilometers per hour then the distance she ran is not $r/12$, it's ... So your second equation is wrong.

Comment: Should be $12r+76f$ not $\frac{r}{12}+\frac{f}{76}$.

Comment: $km = \frac{km}{h} \cdot h $

Comment: Observe that $$\text{distance traveled }=\text{speed}\times\text{time spent}$$

Comment: Ah, thanks for the equation: d = s * t

Comment: (Okay - this is what I did: (-76)($r$+$f$) = 2(-76) = $-76r$-$76f$ = -152 then added the second equation and got: $r$ = 0.5; therefore $f$ = 1.5

Comment: Would this be the correct equation or no?

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! I got my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She ran for $R$ hours at 12 km/h.
She jetpacked for $J$ hours at 76 km/h.

We are told that 
$J+R=2$ (so $J=2-R$)
and that
$12R+76J=120$.

By substituting for $J$ we get:

$12R+76(2-R)=120$

$\Rightarrow 12R+152-76R=120$

$\Rightarrow -64R+152=120$

$\Rightarrow 32=64R$

$\Rightarrow R = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

$\therefore$ She ran for half an hour and jetpacked for one and half hours.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I forgot that I could do: $J = 2 - R$. I really appreciate your help